# infected ubuntu programs?

Tags: security, clamav

My ClamAV antivirus tells me that I have 2 potential threats in my cache. It lists them as PUA.Win.Tool.Packed-177 and PUA.Win.Trojan.Generic-688. Should I be concerned?

Comment: Probably a better discussion on a site that actually works with security concerns.  Both of the tools you've indicated probably loaded into your 'cache' during webbrowsing or are in your temporary internet files.  I'd purge your Internet caches in the respective browsers and remove the files.  However, those files are Windows viruses, not Linux viruses.  (PUA is "Potentially Unwanted Applications" so not necessarily a *virus* on its own.)

Comment: For future readers and to add to @ThomasWard's comment, a "PUA" is a 'potentially unwanted application'. It's not considered a virus, but rather an application that may do things the end-user doesn't want them to do.